# Facebook UserID working with Desktop Version not working in Mobile Device

Tags: facebook

This Code Works fine with Facebook Desktop Versions but not working on Mobile Devices I want to get current User Id .

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"  
       type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script>

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously

    (function (d) {

        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }

        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;

        js.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);

    } (document));



    // Init the SDK upon load
    var called = false;

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXX', // App ID           
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        alert("12");
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("Your UID is " + response.authResponse.userID);
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not_authorized
                alert("3");
                login();
                alert("5");
            } else {
                // not_logged_in
                alert("4");
                login();
            }

        });

    };
    if (!called) {
        alert("Not Called");
        window.fbAsyncInit();
        alert(" Called");
    }
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    }
    function login() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // connected
                testAPI();
            } else {
                // cancelled
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Not working in what sense? Do you have error logs, a specific issue etc?